# jQuery widget - triggering and capturing private events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, widget

I hope someone will help me understand what's going on. In the widget I am building:

`$.widget("myns.usertable", { /* snip */});`

I have to trigger and capture some private events. I have this code:

```
  this._on({
    'keypress .user-input-fld': function(e) {
      switch (e.which) {
        case 13:
          e.preventDefault();
          var item = (inputfld.val());
          addbtn.trigger('itemsubmit', [item]);
          break;
      }
    },
    'itemsubmit.usertable': function(e, item) {
      console.log('itemsubmit', '_on');
      self._addItem(item);
      inputfld.val('').focus();
    }
  });
```

And while the `keypress` part works great, the `itemsubmit.usertable` seems to be never called. Instead, i have to listen like this:

```
  table.bind('itemsubmit.usertable', function(e, item) {
    self._addItem(item);
    inputfld.val('').focus();
  });
```

In general I can go this way, but I would feel more confident if I really understood why it happens so. I would much prefer the `this._on({})` and collection over the event binding scattered all over my code. I feel I'm writing not elegant code, which hurts.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, I found this [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404085.aspx) more helpful than that from jQuery. Sigh.